# Problem viewing photos in Paperclip - routes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, paperclip, rmagick

I have set up Paperclip and ImageMagick successfully on my system, and files are uploading correctly, being resized, and and being saved into the right folders.

I try to display those images in my view:

```
<%= image_tag @customer.logo.url(:medium) %>
```

No image is displayed. When I go to the image's direct url I get:

```
Routing Error
No route matches "/images/assets/logos/1/medium/corplogo.jpg" with {:method=>:get}
```

This is a local server still in development and running on Windows. My forms are multipart:

```
<% form_for @customer, :url => {:action => "update", :id => @customer}, :html => {:multipart => true, :id => "myform"} do |f| %>
```

------ Dev Server ------

Processing ApplicationController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-09-27 04:38:33) [G
ET]
  Parameters: {"1285570273"=>nil}

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/images/assets/logos/1/medium/corplogo.jpg" with {:method=>:get}):
  haml (3.0.15) rails/./lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'

Rendering rescues/layout (not_found)

------ Model ------

```
has_attached_file :logo,
    :url => "assets/logos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/logos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :styles => {:medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

Comment: Three things to check: do you have :medium size defined on your paperclip setup? is the image there at the given path? have you restarted your server?

Comment: Can you show all the debugging of your development server please?

Comment: @dombesz - :medium is defined in the setup, the image is in the right place, and I have restarted the server. :)

Comment: @tommasop - I've added the data above. Thanks

Comment: Can you show `has_attached_file` declaration?

Comment: @Voldy - I've added the declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem, and it lies with the url declaration in the model.

Instead of:

```
:url => "assets/logos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

it should be:

```
:url => "/assets/logos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error using the "webrick" server.  and I check all the file access permission on my "public/system" folder, they are normal.

finally I switched to apache/passenger, it works, the images are displayed correctly.